# how to set the content to radeditor using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, telerik

I am using Radeditor. i need to get the content from clip board and set to editor conten.

i am get the content. but i set the content to editor page, it shows empty.

i am using the following code.

```
 var content = window.clipboardData.getData("Text");

   if (content != null) {
      editor.set_html = content;
```

so i try to bind the content in server side. so i called the server side function using pagemethods.i set EnablePageMethods ="true" in script manager.

but it shows page methods is undefined.

my first priority is set the content using java script.

How to do this?

Thanks,

Pooja

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try Below Code:

```
var newValue = "control alt delete";
    $find("<%=RadEditor1.ClientID%>").set_html(newValue);
```

Regards,

Dhaval Shukla

Answer (score 1):

you can use 2 different methods:

```
    var editor = $find("<%=RadEditor1.ClientID%>");
    var stringVal = window.clipboardData.getData("Text"); 
    if(stringVal != null){
         editor.set_html(stringVal); //replaces the content of the editor with stringVal
         editor.pasteHtml(stringVal); //pastes your string val at the cursor (Defaults to end of the content window if no cursor found)
    }
```

you can get the full API documentation here: http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/editor-pastehtml.html

Answer (score 0):

http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/editor/fill-content-through-javascript-in-telerik-editor.aspx

RadEditor is a composite control and to get a reference to its client object you should use:

```
var editor = $find("<%=RadEditor1.ClientID%>");
var content = window.clipboardData.getData("Text");
if (content != null) {
  editor.set_html = content;
```